# if $f:([0,1],P([0,1])) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$, what are the possible measurable functions?

Tags: measure-theory

if $f:([0,1],P([0,1])) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ and $\mu$ is a measure which is defined as $\mu(A) = 0$ if $|A|\leq\mathbb{N}|$ and $\mu(A) = \infty$ if A is not countable on the sigma algebra $P([0,1])$. what are then the possible functions $f$ for which $f$ is measurable?

functions must sent countable to countable and uncountable to uncountable, but further than that i don't come. I think most functions will succeed in this case, so i can't think of a function that fails

Comment: "functions must sent countable to countable and uncountable to uncountable" Huh? What about checking the *definition* for a function to be measurable?

Comment: yeah of course, one must take the inverse of elements in the Borel sigma algebra and check whether its belongs in the Powerset of $[0,1]$. But if one takes a countable/uncountable set in the borel sigma algebra, the inverse will be countable/uncountable as well and i thought that maybe the measure would fail if i tried both.

Comment: "if one takes a countable/uncountable set in the borel sigma algebra, the inverse will be countable/uncountable as well" First the inverse of a countable set might be uncountable, second this has nothing to do with the question you ask.

Comment: i fail pretty hard here :(

Comment: Back to square one: *What is the condition for a function to be measurable?* Please be specific.

Comment: a function f is measurable if for any $B \in \mathcal{B}$, $f^-1(B) \in P([0,1])$.

Comment: or we could check the generators of course, that works as well

Comment: Good. Now take $B$ in $\mathcal B$. What do you have to check about $f^{-1}(B)$, already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we take the generator of the borel sigma algebra $B = (a,b)$. We then see that $f^{-1}(B)$ is either countable or uncountable, but that means that each function is measurable. So the answer is every well defined function is measurable on these two sigma algebras!

Comment: Not sure that the generator or the countability/uncountability have anything to do with the matter.

Comment: why not? The measure defined on the powerset of $[0,1]$ is defined if either A is countable or A is uncountable right. So each uncountable/countable set is measurable in that space. And if we take the inverse function of an element of the borel sigma algebra, it is countable or uncountable hence measurable right?

Comment: Yes, in other words, un/countability is irrelevant.

Comment: o like that, hahahahahaha yes you're right :P